# Inkscape - Center Drawing to Page via Command Line/Terminal

Tags: inkscape

Is there a way to center the whole drawing to the page in Inkscape with just a Terminal command? I need to do this for a couple hundred images. Manually, you do this by hitting "CTRL+A", "CTRL+ALT+H", "CTRL+ALT+T".

Halfway through writing this question, I figured it out. I'll post the answer.

Answer (score 7):

With "foo.svg" as the image to edit:

```
inkscape --verb=EditSelectAll --verb=AlignHorizontalCenter --verb=AlignVerticalCenter --verb=FileSave --verb=FileQuit foo.svg
```

To edit all svg images in the current directory:

```
inkscape --verb=EditSelectAll --verb=AlignHorizontalCenter --verb=AlignVerticalCenter --verb=FileSave --verb=FileClose *.svg
```

But this second command opens a ton of windows, which will make your computer crash if you're editing too many images. For **Linux only**, this command will work better:

```
for img in *.svg; do inkscape --verb=EditSelectAll --verb=AlignHorizontalCenter --verb=AlignVerticalCenter --verb=FileSave --verb=FileQuit $img ; done
```

For the above command, if any of the files are symlinks, Inkscape will edit the target file that the symlink points  to. If you don't want Inkscape to do this, you can filter out any symlinks with this command:

```
for img in *.svg; do if [[ $(readlink $img) == "" ]] ; then inkscape --verb=EditSelectAll --verb=AlignHorizontalCenter --verb=AlignVerticalCenter --verb=FileSave --verb=FileQuit $img ; fi ; done
```

---

While I'm at it, I might as well post the bash script I made for this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# inkscape-center <file-or-directory>...

_analyse() {
    if [ -d "${1}" ] ; then
        _centerAll "${1}" ;
    else
        _center "${1}" ;
    fi
}

_centerAll() {
    cd "${1}" ;
    for img in *.svg; do
        _filterSyms "${img}" ;
    done
}

_filterSyms() {
    if [[ $(readlink "${1}") == "" ]] ; then
        _center "${1}"
    fi
}

_center() {
    inkscape --verb=EditSelectAll --verb=AlignHorizontalCenter --verb=AlignVerticalCenter --verb=FileSave --verb=FileQuit "${1}"
}

for arg ; do
    _analyse "${arg}" ;
done
```

I called it `inkscape-center` and run it like this:

```
inkscape-center <file-or-directory>
```

It takes as many arguments as you want, so you can do something like this:

```
inkscape-center 1st.svg 2nd.svg 3rd.svg 4th.svg
```

**Be careful**- If you specify a directory instead of a file, it'll edit every svg file in that directory.

Comment: this does not work anymore, since the verbs `AlignHorizontalCenter` are not relative to page, but to selection. I am trying to find out if older inkscape version fixes this (but it is hard to install old inkscape version in the first place, due to all PPAs being updated)

Answer (score 0):

Verbs were removed in 1.1, so now the command for foo.svg is

```
inkscape "--actions=select-all:all;object-align:hcenter vcenter page;export-filename:foo.svg;export-do" foo.svg
```

and the `for` loop is

```
for f in *.svg; do inkscape "--actions=select-all:all;object-align:hcenter vcenter page;export-filename:$f;export-do" $f; done
```