# Inkscape in CLI: FitCanvasToDrawing with margin parameters

Tags: inkscape

I have many files created with adobe illustrator (.ai) on A4 canvas size, and I would like to convert (in CLI) to SVG file to allow their use in a website.

A basic conversion works by running, for example :
`inkscape myFile.ai --export-area-drawing --export-plain-svg myFile.svg`

My issue is the option `export-area-drawing` (or verb `FitCanvasToDrawing`) doesn't let any margin, so display in web page is not nice.

Like GUI properties which allow to add margins, I would like to do the same in CLI, adding 20 pixels on up/down/left/right margins, as capture below at right instead of left
[image: margin-example]

**Is there a way to do that using Inkscape in CLI?**

I read https://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/Using_the_Command_Line, https://inkscape.org/doc/inkscape-man.html, tried to change `fit-margin-…` in file without success.

Of course, I can change website CSS to add

```css
img {
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
}
```

But if we open file in other way, the display stays bad, and if CSS framework change…

I also read on post https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/6670/144183 there is [librsvg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Librsvg)

I am using Inkscape v1.1.1 installed by snap under Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Marc JM](https://inkscape.org/%7EMarcJeanmougin/) answer :
`inkscape --export-area-drawing --export-margin 20 input.ai -o output.svg`
works fine on the v1.1.1 installed on my computer

Comment: Your question was relatively misleading. There is no `fit-margin...` option in the linked web pages. I mistakenly thought that you're referring to `export-margin` and that it doesn't work with `export-area-drawing`

Answer (score 2):

**Update**:

The question was not clear at the first glance and one may think that `export-area-drawing` action doesn't work with `export-margin`. So you can invoke Inkscape as follows:

```
inkscape myFile.ai --actions="export-area-drawing;export-margin:50;export-type:svg;export-plain-svg; export-do" -o myFile.svg
```

**Old answer**:

In Inkscape 1.2-dev there is the action `fit-canvas-to-selection`. To specify the export margin use the `export-margin` action.

The following command should work as expected:

```
inkscape myFile.ai --actions="select-all;fit-canvas-to-selection;export-margin:50;export-type:svg;export-plain-svg; export-do" -o myFile.svg
```

The other actions in that command are self-explanatory.

If that doesn't work for some reason, there is another workaround:

- Use Inkscape to convert your `*.ai` files to PDF.
- use `pdfcrop` utility to crop the PDF documents with custom margins. check `pdfcrop --help` for examples. If you don't have it already installed, try:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install texlive-extra-utils
  ```
- Convert the PDF documents to plain SVG using Inkscape.

Comment: Thanks you for your quick answer, I prefer Marc's answer which works on my release.